# WSO2 IS 520 password recovery issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Steps followed:

- getCaptcha
- verifyUser
- sendNotification
  Receiving the confirmation code in email via link,
  But sending it as a request in confirm code, always return invalid !
  Notification expiry is set 60 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please download wum updated pack and follow the bellow steps.

1. getCaptcha()
2. verifyUser()
3. sendRecoveryNotification()
4. getCaptcha()
5. verifyConfirmationCode()
6. Reset/UpdatePassword()

For more information refer [1] link.
[1]. https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.wso2.com%2Fdisplay%2FIS510%2FPassword%2BRecovery%23PasswordRecovery-Recoveryusingnotifications&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHEOMUWnFUhLsU4m4bVG1OjzAWZ_w

Comment: it works. But the code is not the confirmation code, its the code generated second time, there is no correlation !

Comment: Ensure that the email-­admin-­config.xml file has the following configurations. This file is found in the <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/email directory. please refer the previous document.